# Non-existent .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, heroku

I trying to setup [moodle](https://github.com/eemp/moodle) on Heroku. After adding the code the following error occurs:

```
error 500 /app/.htaccess: AllowOverride not allowed here
```

However, this file does not exist.

I tried to add an empty `.htaccess` but I also get the same error.

Comment: have you enabled hidden files on your OS? I think by default Windows may hide these files^

Comment: Yes. I develop it using Heroku, and I enabled hidden files.